# While using Jackson parser for data name like isDeleted, Parsing issue

Tags: java, spring, parsing, jackson

The mapper call is as follows:

```
String sampleJson; //sample string 
PojoClass data = mapper.readValue(sampleJson, PojoClass.class);
```

The following error is thrown for the isDeleted field:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "isDeleted"

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:60)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:823)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1153)
...
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Its simple pojo class which is throwing an error while parsing
String sampleJson;//sample string
                PojoClass data = mapper.readValue(sampleJson, PojoClass.class);

Comment: Can you post your code in your question, as formatted text (i.e. not in a comment)? Can you include your pojo? A sample of the JSON would also help. More generally, you should try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You should add @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) annotation to your PojoClass.java b/c you're incoming json has a property that isn't defined in your PojoClass (or remove any property in your json that isn't defined in the pojo).

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PojoClass implements Serializable
{
  private String myString ...
}
```